# Imperavi Article (WYSIWYG editor)

Tags: craft3, plugins

Any plans on adding Imperavi's Article WYSIWYG editor to Craft CMS, like Redactor?

Comment: Any news about rumblings :) Imperavi's Article Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question *( Oct 24 2019 )* to the Craft team, so i'll just copy & paste the answer here from Brandon Kelly (Pixel & Tonic):

> Hey Christopher,
>
> We do have plans for a field type like that, but more likely based on
>   editor.js rather than Imperavi's Article Editor.
>
> I have heard rumblings that someone else is working on a plugin based
>   on that though.
>
> -Brandon

Comment: Thanks! Strange it didn't show up as a result when I created this question. Very interesting. Been meaning to delve into expanding some form of visual editor as opposed to matrix/neo fields when applicable.

Comment: The answer was by mail because i signed-up for the developer support. It was not mentioned here on SO :)

Comment: Ah! Got it... :)